# How to count choices in (3, 2000) ndarray faster?

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a way to speed up the following two lines of code?

```
choice = np.argmax(cust_profit, axis=0) 
taken = np.array([np.sum(choice == i) for i in range(n_pr)])
```

```
%timeit np.argmax(cust_profit, axis=0)
37.6 µs ± 222 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit np.array([np.sum(choice == i) for i in range(n_pr)])
40.2 µs ± 206 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

```
n_pr == 2
cust_profit.shape == (n_pr+1, 2000)
```

Solutions:

```
%timeit np.unique(choice, return_counts=True)
53.7 µs ± 190 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
%timeit np.histogram(choice, bins=np.arange(n_pr + 2))
70.5 µs ± 205 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
%timeit np.bincount(choice)
7.4 µs ± 17.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

These microseconds worry me, cause this code locates under two layers of scipy.optimize.minimize(method='Nelder-Mead'), that locates in double nested loop, so 40µs equals 4 hours. And I think to wrap it all in genetic search.

Comment: What are you trying to do conceptually?

Comment: Customers choose one of two offered products. Choice is driven by customer "profit" - difference between product price and inner customer's product value. Cause "profit" can be negative, third row with zeros added to cust_profit array

Comment: Why don't you use `range(n_pr)` for `n_pr=3`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line seems pretty straightforward. Unless you can sort the data or something like that, you are stuck with the linear lookup in `np.argmax`. The second line can be sped up simply by using numpy instead of vanilla python to implement it:

```
v, counts = np.unique(choice, return_counts=True)
```

Alternatively:

```
counts = np.histogram(choice, bins=np.arange(n_pr + 2))
```

A version of `histogram` optimized for integers also exists:

```
count = np.bincount(choice)
```

The latter two options are better if you want to guarantee that the bins include all possible values of `choice`, regardless of whether they are actually present in the array or not.

That being said, you probably shouldn't worry about something that takes microseconds.

Comment: Grazie very much!

Comment: @senderle. Thanks, I added it to the answer